# Kotlin wait for async with coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to open a new activity when phoneViewModel and ScanViewModel are instantiated. They are instantiated by calling an async function InitialRead(). I'm logging each step, atm they are logged as done3 => done2 => done1

I would like to have them in this order:
done1 => done2 => done3

I have following code:

```
class MainBusinessActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var scanViewModel: ScanViewModel
private lateinit var phoneViewModel: PhoneViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_business)
}

private fun startEntitySetListActivity() = GlobalScope.async {
    val sapServiceManager = (application as SAPWizardApplication).sapServiceManager
    sapServiceManager?.openODataStore {
        phoneViewModel =  ViewModelProvider(this@MainBusinessActivity).get(PhoneViewModel::class.java).also {it.initialRead{Log.e("done", "done1")}}
        scanViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this@MainBusinessActivity).get(ScanViewModel::class.java).also {it.initialRead{Log.e("done", "done2")}}
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    //startEntitySetListActivity()
    runBlocking {
        startEntitySetListActivity().await()
        val intent = Intent(this@MainBusinessActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        Log.e("done", "done3")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong? Can someone correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `runBlocking` in an Android app. `runBlocking` completely defeats the purpose of using coroutines, and can lead to an ANR. You also probably should never use `GlobalScope`, which leads to UI leaks. You might possibly need it for some kind of long-running task that doesn't make sense to put in a service but doesn't have dependency on any UI components, but I can't think of any examples

You also shouldn't be instantiating your ViewModels in the background. That should be done in `onCreate()`.

Make this function a suspend function, and it can break down the two tasks in the background simultaneously before returning.

Start your coroutine with `lifecycleScope`.

Assuming `sapServiceManager?.openODataStore` is an asynchronous task that takes a callback, you will need to wrap it in `suspendCoroutine`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_business)
    phoneViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this@MainBusinessActivity).get(PhoneViewModel::class.java)
    scanViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this@MainBusinessActivity).get(ScanViewModel::class.java)
}

private suspend fun startEntitySetListActivity() = coroutineScope {
    val sapServiceManager = (application as SAPWizardApplication).sapServiceManager
    sapServiceManager ?: return
    suspendCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->
        sapServiceManager.openODataStore { continuation.resume(Unit) }
    }
    listOf(
        launch {
            phoneViewModel.initialRead{Log.e("done", "done1")}
        },
        launch {
            scanViewModel.initialRead{Log.e("done", "done2")}
        }
    ).joinAll()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        startEntitySetListActivity()
        val intent = Intent(this@MainBusinessActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        Log.e("done", "done3")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm getting unresolved reference for launch and lifecycleScope. Do I need to declare them or import them?

Comment: Maybe you are missing the build dependency on `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx`?

Comment: I was also missing the `coroutineScope` wrapper. Just fixed it above.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem remaining is that my viewmodel must be instantiated inside the  openODataStore{HERE}. Else I'm getting Cannot create instance of class PhoneViewModel

Comment: I don't understand what that class or function is, or how your ViewModel instantiation could require it when you are not passing anything to the ViewModel factory from that lambda.

Comment: But if PhoneViewModel requires it to already be called, you could put the line where you create the view model right after the `suspendCoroutine` block. I'm assuming that function is an asynchronous function with a callback. But it seems to me there is a design flaw if the ViewModel is relying on something like that but is instantiated with the default ViewModel factory.